# Java -jar using Oracle lib

Tags: command-line, java, openjdk, jdk, oracle

I have installed java-7-openjdk and it works well, but I need to use JavaFX in a project so I download "Java SE" (all packages) form Oracle and I store them inside`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45`.

Now I want to execute `Ensemble.jar` that is a set of examples of JavaFX.

I try `java -jar Ensemble.jar` but it doesn't work because by default Ubuntu doesn't use my Oracle packages.

Can I execute `Ensemble.jar` using not the default Java but my donwloaded packets??

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

```
mimeopen Ensemble.jar
```

the above command display some options.

You have to select `other` and after use the path to your java folder, in this case `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/jexec`